# Sleeping facilities at Chennai International Airport

Tags: india, airports, layovers, sleeping, maa

I was just going through this  [sleeping in airports](http://www.sleepinginairports.net/asia/chennai.htm#wifi) link for Chennai International Airport. And quite excited to see that there are `Retiring Rooms` at reasonable rates. However, it does not provide any information on:

If they are open 24 hours a day? I would be arriving at around 00:15 in the International terminal on a Monday and would like to stay till 05:00. My next flight is from the domestic terminal.

Also, if there is anybody who has used this, do let me know what facilities are there and whether it is worth it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can confirm that these facilities are open 24 hours.
https://twitter.com/aaichnairport/status/784238482134708227

Comment: I do not think the retiring room is open anymore. It was the case last year, at least when I tried